# Numerical calculation of fisher information

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation, statistical-inference

I am trying to obtain numerically the fisher information. Given a likelihood function
$$ f(X,\theta),$$
with $X \in [0,1]$.
The fisher information is given by
$$ \mathbb{I}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left[\left. \frac{\partial^2 \text{log }f( X|\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}\right|_{\theta=\theta^*} \right].$$

To calculate this numerically in Matlab is use this formula:
$$\mathbb{I}(\theta) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 \text{log }f( X|\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} \cdot f(X,\theta) \quad dX$$

Am I doing this correct?

Comment: @Learner Yes ,it is. I corrected my question.

Comment: There is a negative sign missing and $\theta^\star$ should be equal to $\theta$.

Comment: @Learner, thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the distribution of X? i.e. what is the functional form of f(x)? Since most Fisher Information problems are defined in terms of the parameters, you may find that you need symbolic methods, not numerical ones.

Answer (score 1):

The formula i've always used is,
    \begin{equation}
     \mathbb{I}_{ij}(\theta) = \int\limits_\mathbb{R} f(x,\theta)   \frac{\partial \ln f(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta_{i}} \frac{\partial ln \ f(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta_{j}} dx 
    \end{equation}